# List comprehension and converting string to object

Tags: haskell, converters

I have a string, like `2.7+i*3.4`. I want to parse this string and get `Complex number` object. I try to do this:

```
newtype MyComplexNumber = MyComplexNumber (Complex Float)

myReadsCmplx s = [(MyComplexNumber (a :+ b)) |
                               (a, '+':r1) <- reads s :: [(Float, String)],
                               (i, '*':r2) <- reads r1 :: [(String, String)],
                               (b, r3) <- reads r2 :: [(Float, String)]]
```

But I have empty list:

```
*Main Data.Complex> myReadsCmplx "2.7+i*3.4"
[]
*Main Data.Complex>
```

Comment: You are `read`ing a string `i`: reading a `String` expects quotes like `reads "\"i\""`, hence it fails.

Comment: @chi, hm, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You could remove these chars as you do for the `+`, e.g. `(a, '+':'i':'*':r1) <- reads s`. Then `r1` would just contain the last float. This is still a bit fragile because it will fail if there's a space between the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `reads` as though it were a full monadic parser. It's not. It comes up with a match or none, and if the match it finds does not match your pattern, you get nada. You will be much better off using something like `parsec`, `attoparsec`, or even something super-simple like `regex-applicative`.

Comment: Or http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#t:ReadP , which ghc actually uses to implement `Read` (cf. https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Read.hs )

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42, yes, that looks like another good option. There are lots of good options.

Comment: @dfeuer, thank you for answer. What do you mean, when you say: "you get nada"?